# Quartz.Net Initializing Project

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am new to Quartz.Net and I have been following [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/17/quartz.net-writing-your-first-hello-world-job.aspx) tutorial to do my first Job.
I followed every step and started from zero 3 times but I cannot make this to work.
When I run the project on Visual Studio I get this message from the cmd:

```
Failed: Could not load file or assembly: 'HelloWorldDotNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On Visual Studio output I get:

> 'HelloWorldQuartzDotNet.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   no configuration section  found - suppressing logging output
>   'HelloWorldQuartzDotNet.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I cannot understand what that mscorlib.dll is... I tried to search for that and I couldn't get anywhere.
I am using the recent version of Quartz.Net 2.2.1 on Windows 8.

Comment: meanwhile was released v2.2.2 that I cant make it work also. Nobody?

Comment: Do you have your configuration via xml or an ado-store?  If xml, then please post the xml.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading project and following step-by-step tutorial, I found problem with it, after a some time spent in debugger. So tutorial will guide you from client side perspective on using `Quartz.NET`, and there are no problems with it. Code is building fine, and everything works like a charm. Problem is on server side of project, and error you are getting is sent from service that is running `Quartz.NET` server implementation. Line throwing an exception is:

```
// Line 40 | ScheduleJob.cs
var schedule = schd.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

What's happening here is that scheduler is informed about new job called `WriteHelloToConsole` for `HelloWorldJob` class implementing IJob interface. Once server receives this information, he tries to find that dll within his application domain (here comes problem). However, there are no `HelloWorldJob` in Quartz.NET server domain (folder), since you have downloaded it directly from the SourceForge server. That is reason why you are getting **could not load file or assembly**.

**Solution** is simple, yet not recommended, but for this tutorial sufficient. You just need to copy/paste `HelloWorldQuartzDotNet.exe` into the `Quart.NET` service folder and start/stop service from `Windows Services`. Once you do this, it will load `HelloWorldJob` class (and also other classes from HelloWorldQuartzDotNet.exe) in `Quartz.NET` server application domain.

**Recommended solution** for other project, specially for production. Create separate DLL for each of your, so one DLL for `IJob` class and separate DLL for `Quartz.NET`. Add references to the client and copy/paste DLLs to service. This way you will have everything decoupled and you will get maintainable solution.

If you need more about how .NET application domain works, you can get it from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxk374d9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

---

**Note:**
Best way to start/learn/play with Quartz .NET is with their documentation. There is a handy tutorial on how to setup everything from small console app to the windows service. I have implemented it several times, only using documentation.

> [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html)

I'm willing to help for any particular question.

Comment: The documentation does not cover this bug.

Comment: This could be a lot of things, I think it's not Quartz.NET problem, rather VS/.NET. If you have project to share I will take a look.

Comment: Figure it out, I updated answer with correct solution for given problem. Just let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Mscorlib.dll is a class library which contains core functions of the .NET framework and it is clearly letting you know that it cannot find HelloWorldDotNet assembly by throwing `FileNotFoundException`...

Make sure that your `HelloWorldDotNet` assembly builds fine. Check what is your StartUp project in Visual Studio and make sure it is correct and has a reference to this assembly. Check all the references in your project...

Comment: I tried to add mscorlib as reference and I get the following message: "A reference to mscorlib could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system". Although I had the target framework to 4.5, I also changed that to 4.0 and still don't work.

Comment: @JoãoMartins - this has nothing to do with mscorlib. this has to d with your application that you did not deploy with the solution called "HelloWorldDotNot"

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I have all the possible names called "HelloWorldQuartzDotNet". I don't know what more I can do

Comment: @JoãoMartins - are you using Quartz.NET from NuGet or did you reference the quartz assembly manually? Can we have some sample code?

Comment: @cvbarros I am using references from NuGet. I am just trying to get that simple tutorial in the original post to work. Some guys are reporting in the comments section of the tutorial the same error that I have but nobody answers. Although in the comments section there are people talking about this: "
It is necessary that your job dll is available in the folder. How you get it there is your choice. Also note that the service needs to be restarted after the job dll has been placed there."
but I don't understand what job dll are they talking about or in what folder it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Check solution properties.
Have you checked optimize code checkbox there?
Try unchecking it and then compile and run.